# Execute iwlist and iwconfig binary file on Android

Tags: java, android, executable, runtime.exec, android-wireless

Recently I need to Accelerate the scan speed of wifi, so I use the tool of Iwlist and Iwconfig. downloaded from :https://github.com/nvamelichev/wireless-tools-android

After Compiling, I put these two binary file to /system/xbin/ with proper permission.
It works fine on the app of "Terminal emulator"
but when I try to execute them in my own app. it does not work....
Here is my code:

```
        iwProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iwlist --version");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iwProcess.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();
        iwProcess.waitFor();

        String nativeOutput = output.toString();
        mTextView.setText(nativeOutput);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iwProcess.getErrorStream()));
        while ((read = br.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            sb.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        br.close();
        mTextView.setText(output + sb.toString());
```

the result is "socket address family not supported by protocol" that really confuse me....